# A Foreign key refering MasterDataEntity from MainTableEntity has the wrong number of column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, entity

I have a master data table. The use of this table is to just hold the data (as such it has no relationship with other tables).

This is MasterDataEntity

```
@Id
@Column(name = "TYPE_ID")
private Integer id;

@Id
@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;
```

In one of the other table (a functional table), I want to join this table. Like:

This is the MainTableEntity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "TYPE_ID")
private MasterDataEntity masterDataEntity;
```

The logical intent here is that Maintable should contain one of the Type_Id of the MasterTable (not mandatory of all the rows even).

I do not want to store any kind of information on MainTable in the MasterTable. All I want is only existing values from the master table can be added to the main table.

Apart from the above, I did the following queries to mark the FK relation:

```
ALTER TABLE MAIN_TABLE ADD TYPE_ID NUMBER;

ALTER TABLE MAIN_TABLE ADD FOREIGN KEY (TYPE_ID ) REFERENCES MASTER_TABLE(TYPE_ID );
```

With the above code I get the error:
A Foreign key referring MasterDataEntity from MainTableEntity has the wrong number of column. should be 2.

I tried looking at the root cause but could not get any helpful info. I am new to Hibernate and it is possible I might be doing wrong things based on my requirements.

Can someone suggest what is wrong here and what should I be doing to achieve my intent?

Thanks

P.S: I have mentioned only the relevant info. There are obviously many other columns in MainEntity, while MasterEntity has just 2 columns. Let me know if any info is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because of `MasterDataEntity` have multiple primary key, since `id` and `description` fields have `@Id` Annotation, 
It should just have one which is for `TYPE_ID` :

```
@Id
@Column(name = "TYPE_ID")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;
```

Comment: I can't believe that after scanning these files for hundred times, I didn't notice the blunder. I am sure that is the issue. Still I will check it and revert.

Comment: Indeed, that was it.